# To insert an image image into a custom object through apex code

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am working in LWC.I am tryin to insert an image into a custom object via apex code.

**HTML**

```
<lightning-input
                label="Upload"
                name="file uploader"
                onchange={handleFilesChange}
                type="file"
                
              ></lightning-input>

 <lightning-button
                  label="Save"
                  variant="brand"
                  onclick={handleClick}
                ></lightning-button>
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement , wire, track, api} from 'lwc';
import newClient from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.newClient';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class PriceScreen extends LightningElement {
 @track fileName = '';
    filesUploaded = [];
    file;
    fileContents;
    fileReader;
    content;
    MAX_FILE_SIZE = 1500000;

  handleFilesChange(event) {
        if(event.target.files.length > 0) {
            this.filesUploaded = event.target.files;
            this.fileName = event.target.files[0].Id;
            this.uploadHelper();
        }
    }

    uploadHelper() {
        this.file = this.filesUploaded[0];
       if (this.file.size > this.MAX_FILE_SIZE) {
            window.console.log('File Size is to long');
            return ;
        }
    
        // create a FileReader object 
        this.fileReader= new FileReader();
        // set onload function of FileReader object  
        this.fileReader.onloadend = (() => {
            this.fileContents = this.fileReader.result;
            let base64 = 'base64,';
            this.content = this.fileContents.indexOf(base64) + base64.length;
            this.fileContents = this.fileContents.substring(this.content);
            
            // call the uploadProcess method 
          
        });
    
        this.fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    }

 handleClick(event) {
  
  
 
    newClient({ photo:this.fileName,base64Data: encodeURIComponent(this.fileContents)})
      

   .then(result => {
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Saved succesfully',
        variant: 'success',
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    
     })

   .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
        alert("FAILURE" + error);
        
   });

 
    }
}
```

**APEX CLASS**

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = false)
    public static Boolean newClient( String photo,String base64Data ){
        base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data, 'UTF-8');
        String imageSource = Url.getFileFieldURL(photo, EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data));
       
       Client__c client = new Client__c();
      
       client.Photo__c =  '<img src="'+imageSource+'" />';

       try {
        insert client;
        return true;
           
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new AuraHandledException('exceptionText' + e.getMessage());
         
       }
      
    }
```

> String imageSource = Url.getFileFieldURL(Photo,
> EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data));// error in this line(Unknown
> label 'Photo')

In the above line, `EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data)` is the 'VersionData'. While deploying to org, It shows an error, unknown label 'Photo'. Is there anymistake in my code?

Comment: ` Url.getFileFieldURL` accepts string input parameters. Check out the dev guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm?search_text=getFileFieldURL. You have incorrectly used this method. Correct it as specified in the dev guide.

Comment: Url.getFileFieldURL(Photo, EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data));

Comment: I refered the dev guide link, so I need to place the file id as the entityid and file field api name in the custom object ie 'Photo__c' as the second parameter. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Does anyone have any example code?